# Running WINE on google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is it possible to run a windows application through WINE on google compute engine?

1. Create a custom image
2. Install wine
3. Install windows app in wine.

I think in theory it should be possible, what bothers me is that usually with wine one is using an interactive GUI. The windows app, once installed, is going to be used on the command line, however. So perhaps, I could create a custom image locally (with wine and windows executable) and then use that?

Has anybody had practical experience or can offer an informed speculation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  In testing this, I have successfully run a windows binary of netcat on a GCE machine:

```
$ wine nc.exe www.google.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.0

<... a bunch of html ...>
```

I initially set it up with an X11 forwarding session, which wine seems to need to be happy.  From a machine with an X server, try `ssh -Y <instance ip>` and then run `apt-get install wine` or `yum install wine` depending on your linux flavor.